# MAUI: Dependency injection is not working

Tags: maui

I have a dependency injection in my project for getting the device unique id. It is working fine in my `xamarin forms` project, but when I add it on my `MAUI` project the result is blank.

**My code**

**IDevice**

```
public interface IDevice
{
    string GetIdentifier();
}
```

**AndroidDevice**

```
public class AndroidDevice : IDevice
{
    public string GetIdentifier()
    {
        return Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
    }
}
```

**IOSDevice**

```
public class IOSDevice : IDevice
{
    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit")]
    private static extern uint IOServiceGetMatchingService(uint masterPort, IntPtr matching);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit")]
    private static extern IntPtr IOServiceMatching(string s);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit")]
    private static extern IntPtr IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(uint entry, IntPtr key, IntPtr allocator, uint options);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit")]
    private static extern int IOObjectRelease(uint o);

    public string GetIdentifier()
    {
        string serial = string.Empty;
        uint platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(0, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));
        if (platformExpert != 0)
        {
            NSString key = (NSString)"IOPlatformSerialNumber";
            IntPtr serialNumber = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, key.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            if (serialNumber != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                serial = NSString.FromHandle(serialNumber);
                //serial = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.ToString();
            }
            IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);
        }
        return serial;
    }
}
```

On this [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4670) I have seen adding the dependency service to DI services.

```
.Services.AddTransient<IGetDeviceInfo, GetDeviceInfo>();
```

But when I added that, the `AndroidDevice` class is not found error is showing like the below screenshot.

[image]

> The type or namespace name 'AndroidDevice' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you used the dependency service in the xamarin.form to call the platform natvie code. But in the maui, the dependency service can be replaced by the Conditional compilation or Partial classes.

1. Use the Conditional compilation: Put the following code in the share project:

```
    string Identifier;
#if Android
    Identifier = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
#elif IOS
        uint platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(0, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));
        if (platformExpert != 0)
        {
            NSString key = (NSString)"IOPlatformSerialNumber";
            IntPtr serialNumber = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, key.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            if (serialNumber != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Identifier = NSString.FromHandle(serialNumber);
                //Identifier = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.ToString();
            }
            IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);
        }
#endif
```

2. Use the partial class:

In the ShareProject:

```
public partial class GetDevice : IDevice
{
   public partial string GetIdentifier();
}
```

In the **\Platforms\Android** folder:

```
public partial class GetDevice : IDevice
{
    public partial string GetIdentifier()
    {
        return global::Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
    }
}
```

The ios is the same. And then you can use `.Services.AddTransient<IGetDevice, GetDevice>();`

Comment: `Use the Conditional compilation: Put the following code in the share project:`. Where should I add the above section codes, on which file?

Comment: Is it added on the page where we are fetching device identifier? Is there any change on the ios GetIdentifier codes? For ios also should I give the same name for class `GetDevice` like android?

Comment: The first question: put it where you want to get the device identifier. For the second question, for the particial class, the class name should be same between android and ios(even every platform). @SreejithSree